# Cywgin Sed match not working when "/" in string

Tags: regex, bash, sed, special-characters

```
testLine="This is a test line: Asia/Pacific Australia"
expr="Asia\/Pacific Australia"
```

This works:

```
echo "$testLine" | sed 's/Asia\/Pacific Australia/TEST/g'
```

This DOES NOT:

```
echo "$testLine" | sed 's/$expr/TEST/g'
```

I've tried everything from using multiple "escapes", using different quote marks, using `-r` and `-re` Sed switches. Nothing seems to work.

Please advise if anyone has a working solution. Please can someone advise and provide the Cygwin output here, many thanks!

Comment: `$expr` isn't expanded inside single quotes.

Comment: OMD! Cheers thanks a lot chepner!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change your variable as

```
expr="Asia/Pacific Australia"
```

this should work then

```
echo "$testLine" | sed 's_'"$expr"'_TEST_g'
```

note that for sed delimiters you can choose other chars as well, here `_`

Comment: It was because of the single quotes as mentioned by "chepner" above which you have also eluded to in the answer, many thanks!